# Hide the StimulSoft Report record on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I use stimulssoft report mvc for generating a report in an Visual studio 2015 website.

There is no problem with the local host and all the records in the report are displayed.

But when the software is uploaded to the server there is no record in my StimulSoft Report to my users.

There is this problem for 2 days there is not this problem before.